# Can an HTTP Proxy be configured with Web API?

Tags: http, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I would like to build an HTTP proxy that routes all requests to another HTTP service.  Does anyone have any good suggestions as to how to achieve this with Web-API?

The situation I have is that we have 2 groups of services.  One is externally accessible, and one isn't.  I want to provide a router from the external services to call my internal services where all the logic and configuration lies.

Comment: You sure you don't just want to use something that's widely available and has good community support? [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/), [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main), [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/), [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very easy to do.  Just create a class that derives from DelegatingHandler, override SendAsync and add it to the MessageHandlers collection on your configuration object.

Here a self hosted console application proxy that I created that converts JSON to XML and vise-versa.  It should give you the idea of how it is done.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8081");
        var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);


        var originServerUri = new Uri("http://example.org/origin-server/");      
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new Converter(originServerUri));

        server.OpenAsync().Wait();

        Console.Read();

        server.CloseAsync().Wait();

    }
}


public class Converter : DelegatingHandler
{
    private HttpClient _HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    private Uri _OriginServer;
    public Converter(Uri originServer)
    {
        _OriginServer = originServer;
    }
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
           Console.WriteLine(new HttpMessageContent(request).ReadAsStringAsync().Result);


            var newRequest = CreateNewRequest(request);

            var t = _HttpClient.SendAsync(newRequest);

            await t;

            if (t.IsCompleted)
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = CreateNewResponse(t.Result);
                    Console.WriteLine("--->");
                    Console.WriteLine(new HttpMessageContent(response).ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    return response;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(ex.Message)};

                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(t.Exception.Message)};
            }
    }

    private HttpRequestMessage CreateNewRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage();

        newRequest.Headers.Clear();
        foreach (var header in request.Headers)
        {
            newRequest.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
        if (request.Content.Headers.ContentLength != 0)
        {
            newRequest.Content = TranslateContent(request.Content);
        }
        newRequest.Headers.Host = null;
        newRequest.Method = request.Method;
        newRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(_OriginServer, request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery);
        return newRequest;
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage CreateNewResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        response.Content = TranslateContent(response.Content);
        return response;
    }

    private HttpContent TranslateContent(HttpContent httpContent)
    {
        var mediatype = httpContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
        if (mediatype.Contains("+xml"))
        {
            return TranslateXmlToJson(httpContent);
        }
        else
        {
            return TranslateJsonToXml(httpContent);
        }
    }

    private HttpContent TranslateJsonToXml(HttpContent content)
    {
        var mediatype = content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;

        string json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
        return new StringContent(doc.OuterXml, Encoding.UTF8, mediatype.Replace("+json", "+xml"));
    }

    private HttpContent TranslateXmlToJson(HttpContent content)
    {
        var mediatype = content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);

        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
        return new StringContent(jsonText, Encoding.UTF8, mediatype.Replace("+xml", "+json"));
    }


}
```

Comment: The DelegatingHandler needs to be configured on the client sending the request right?  I to set this up server-side.  If I can't use this I guess I could always inspect the HttpRequest and re-direct it manually.

Comment: @crankage  No in this case you would be using a delegating handler on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses guys.  In the end I decided to go with an IHttpHandler as the service where the proxy is needed was currently not using web-api.  This was done by doing something like:

```
public class MyProxy : IHttpHandler
{
    private static readonly string CoreServicesUrl = "localhost:1234";

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string serviceUrl = context.Request.Headers.Get("ServiceUrl");
        if (serviceUrl == null)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return;
        }

        string url = string.Format("http://{0}/api/{1}", CoreServicesUrl, serviceUrl);
        HttpResponseMessage response = RouteRequest(context, url);

        // This will handle both successful and unsuccessful responses
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        context.Response.Write(content);
    }

    private static HttpResponseMessage RouteRequest(HttpContext context, string url)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
            return client.GetAsync(url).Result;

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            var stream = context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream();
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            var body = sr.ReadToEnd();
            try
            {
                return client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) {ReasonPhrase = ex.Message};
                return response;
            }
        }

        // Other HTTP verbs are not supported
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
    }        

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```